# Different behaviour between Typescript in ts files and in jsdoc

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

Different override behaviour in Typescript and Typescript in jsdoc. I think I do something wrong. There is no much info in documentation about Typescriptin jsdoc. See example below.

Typescript version: 3.5.3

.tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "*.js",
    "*.ts"
  ]
}
```

valid typescript in js file

```
class A {
    /**
     * @param {number} a
     * @returns {string}
     */
    apply(a) {
        return "";
    }
}

/**
 * @extends {A}
 */
class B extends A {
    /**
     * @param {object} a
     * @returns {string}
     */
    apply(a) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

invalid typescript in ts file

```
class A {
    apply(a: number): string {
        return "";
    }
}

class E extends A {
    apply(some: object) { // got error here as function signature is different
        return "";
    }
}
```

expect same error in `A.js`

Answer (score 0):

object, doesnt mean anything in typescript, use Object, with a capital 'O' instead

Comment: Actually `object` is a type in TypeScript.